# How do I remove a nested nav from all top-level listed items, except for one, using an array in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I would like to remove the nested list named $subPages from displaying under all of the top-level lists named $pages, except for Services.

My attempt is allowing the nested list items to display under all three top-level items.

**How do I remove a nested nav from all top-level listed items, except for one i.e., 'Services' using an array in PHP only?**

```php
    <nav class="navBar wAuto fRight positAb">
            <?php
                $pages = array(
                '/about/' => 'About',
                '/services/' => 'Services',
                '/book-a-service/' => 'Book a service'
                );
    
                $subPages = array(
                '/services/bathroom-installation' => 'Bathroom installation',
                '/services/boiler-repair' => 'Boiler repair',
                '/services/boiler-service' => 'Boiler service',
                '/services/gas-oil' => 'Gas &amp; oil',
                '/services/heat-recovery' => 'Heat recovery',
                '/services/heating-plumbing' => 'Heating and plumbing',
                '/services/rainwater-harvesting' => 'Rainwater harvesting',
                '/services/solar-solutions' => 'Solar solutions',
                '/services/underfloor-heating' => 'Underfloor heating'
                );
                $activePage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                //open nav
    
            foreach( $pages as $url => $anchor){
                $activeClass = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $url) ? " active" : "";
                echo '<li class="fLeft"><a class="font13'.$activeClass.'" href="'.$url.'"';
    
                if($url == '/services/'){
                    echo 'id="parent"';
                };
    
                if($url == '/book-a-service/'){
                    echo 'id="ctaUHP"';
                    echo '>'.$anchor.'</a>';
                    //Open nested nav
                };
    
                if(isset($url) == '/services/'){
                    echo '<ul class="wAuto positAb">';
                    foreach($subPages as $url => $anchor){
                        echo '<li class="fullWidth"><a class="font10" href="'.$url.'"';//open nested nav
                        echo '>'.$anchor.'</a></li>';
                    }
                };
    
                //Close nested nav
                echo '</li></ul>';
                //Close submenu
            }
    
            //Close nav
            echo '</ul>';
         ?>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code for open nested nav, change `if(isset($url) == '/services/')` to `if($url == '/services/'){`

**Explanation:** You don't need to verify if the `$url` is set, you just need to print the nested nav when your `$url == '/services/'`, that's why you need to remove the function `isset()` :)

---

**EDIT**

You lacked some `{}` and I even rearranged some of your code, so now looks like this :)

```
echo '<ul>'; //open nav

foreach( $pages as $url => $anchor) {
    $activeClass = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $url) ? " active" : "";

    echo '<li class="fLeft"><a class="font13'.$activeClass.'" href="'.$url.'"';

    if($url == '/services/') {
        echo 'id="parent"';
    }

    if($url == '/book-a-service/') {
        echo 'id="ctaUHP"';
    }

    echo '>'.$anchor.'</a>';

    //verify if exists nested nav
    if($url == '/services/') {
        echo '<ul class="wAuto positAb">'; //open nested nav

        foreach ($subPages as $url => $anchor) {
            echo '<li class="fullWidth"><a class="font10" href="'.$url.'">'.$anchor.'</a></li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>'; //close nested nav
     }

     echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>'; //close nav
```

Comment: Thank you, Ju. That helps, but the printed code is jumbled: the <ul> closes after the first top-level list item. Is there a way to edit the printed code, please?

Comment: @GrahamO'Mahony I edited my answer and now it's working properly :) Sorry for taking so long!

Comment: Muito obrigado, Ju! It worked and I was able to understand the changes you made. You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome @GrahamO'Mahony :) I'm glad to help and even more happy to know that you understand the changes :)
Now please accept my answer as correct in order to let the others know and help in case someone need it.. thanks!! :D